# Significance testing in r 5% level

Tags: r, regression, p-value, t-test

If a variable in a regression is statistically significant at the 0.1% level does that automatically mean it's also significant at the 5% level? I got the output for my variables with *** and now want to find out whether that automatically infers that they are also significant at a 5% level.

Comment: I believe this question is better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/. The answer provided by @Ben-Bolker below is absolutely correct, but on the stats forum you will find a lot of discussion on this topic that might be helpful in future e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3202

Answer (score 0):

Yes. (If `p<0.001` that implies, mathematically, that it must be `<0.05` as well ...)